# After moving Wordpress, login works, but no admin access anymore

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-login

After transferring a wordpress from an old ISP to a new ISP, I have trouble with the admin access / access to the dashboard.

The transfer was done by copying all files (incl. .htaccess) from the old server to the new server, dumping the old DB and putting it on the new server and adjust all settings for DB in wp-config.php.

By setting a hosts entry on my machine, I could verify that everything is working fine and all content appears.

Here is my problem.

After logging in thru wp-login.php with old and new credentials (manually added admin account for example) the login is happening, redirecting me to the website, stating successful login by the login bar on the top of the page, but access to the dashboard is prohibited by stating.

```
Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.
```

The login bar also has nearly no options except of going to wordpress.com or logout.

This is probably just a small thing and I just need someone that points me into the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out that this is a bug within Wordpress 4.6.1 when using your own prefix for DB table names.

Rename to wp_ prefix and change the table names and it works.

Answer (score 22):

Found the perfect solution for me.

Problem was not with the migrating of the database to the new server but, if in migration prefix is different in old as well as in new database then the issue occurs!

My original database prefix was something like **wp_71XXXXXX28_** and in the new installation, I was using **wp_**. Changing prefix only just solve the data part, but the log in issue still there as you have.

So, I just simply search for the old prefix in all tables using phpmyadmin search option for **wp_71XXXXXX28_** and change the records to **wp_**.

Note: I found 5-6 matches in **wp_user** and 1 match in **wp_option**, yours might be different!

Comment: I had similar problem,  when i moved site from local host to server for some reason tables names are changed to lowercase   after renaming problem fixed.

Comment: I found the old prefixes in *_option and *_usermeta, not *_user.

Comment: Lifesaver... I would never guess this was the reason. Fault on me for not checking the site after the migration before changing the prefix LOL

Answer (score 8):

this may be because of you change the table name manually then this error show.
so also change table prefix into the 'usermeta' table in 'meta_key' column

previousprefixthatyouchangeinnew_ to

- yourPrefix_capability
- yourprefix_user_level
- yourprefix_user-settings
- yourprefix_user-settings-time

your problem has been solved.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like your problem is with the manually created admin account. The error message you're seeing suggests to me that there's an issue with the permissions assigned to the user.

Can you tell me more about the steps you took to manually add the account?

I'm guessing you added the user directly to the users table but after doing so, did you add capabilities and user level information to the usermeta table?

To give you an example, if I'm creating a user I'd run a query to insert the user into the `wp_users` table (assuming of course we're on the standard table prefix).

I'd then get the ID of my newly created user and use it to insert two new rows into `wp_usermeta`.

`umeta_id` should be NULL and `user_id` should be the ID of your new user for both entries.

```
1)
meta_key: wp_capabilities
meta_value: a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";}

2)
meta_key: wp_user_level
meta_value: 10
```

Further reading: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database-via-mysql/

Comment: I think I have all set up correctly. This is what I added:  `code`  INSERT INTO `wp_users` (`ID`, `user_login`, `user_pass`, `user_nicename`, `user_email`, `user_status`, `display_name`) VALUES ('1000', 'david', MD5('willoverwritewithcorrectPW'), 'David', 'david@gmail.com', '0', 'David');
INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '1000', 'wp_capabilities', 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}');
INSERT INTO `wp_usermeta` (`umeta_id`, `user_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES (NULL, '1000', 'wp_user_level', '10');

Comment: I followed all other instructions but creating a new admin with this code did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have also encountered this message after a migration.

Seems like database prefix is case-sensitive, and if it doesn't match exactly, this is what pops up when trying to access administration pages.

Make sure you check your config.php and set it exactly as your table prefix.

If you use phpMyAdmin to check the tables, you should note that all table names in database tree are displayed in lower case, while in my case the expected prefix was all upper cased.

---

phpMyAdmin image: [phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER2h1.jpg)

The right prefix in the image is the one that should be used.

I used "<prefix>_usermeta" table to get the prefix WP expected.

Comment: uu01's suggestion worked for me... I checked the DB and the prefix actually had some mixed case... when I changed that in my wp_config file to the same mixed case as the DB then I got into the backend. Thanks uu01

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that is still looking for the right answer in my case this what I did to fix the problem of not being able to login to WordPress Dashboard.

In database 'wp_options' table under 'wp_user_roles' option name, all the standard capabilities were missing. Copy those capabilities from database backup or from clean WordPress database.

Answer (score 0):

When you use search & replace on the dumped .sql file of the original wordpress site to use it on the new one, ensure you covered all.
I had the same problem and checking the wp_usermeta table, in the meta_key column I discovered some keys named after the old table prefix. Replacing them fixed my problem.