# Can't access the Wordpress dashboard when logged in

Tags: wordpress

I migrated the company's website on a new hosting server. Since then, I cannot access my Wordpress dashboard when I'm logged in.

When connected, I see my website and the classic Wordpress top bar. But when I click on the button with the name of my website (usually that sends me to the dashboard) it just sends me back to the home page.

I add that the top bar isn't *really* like the classic top bar since it doesn't contain any option.

Here's a screenshot.

[The top of my website when logged with the top bar of the admin wordpress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eH7k.png)

Clicking "Bonjour Signature_Beta" doesn't do anything. I can only log out.

Going to the /wp-admin page gives me an error saying "Sorry, you do not have authorization to reach this page". Except, I'm supposed to have authorization since my profile has a wp_content value of a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;} and wp_user_level of 10.

I have tried multiple things I found online that didn't come to fruition sadly :

- Renaming plugin's folder (nothing changes except page breaking because they're made with Elementor)
- Renaming theme's and child theme's folder (page goes blank, top bar still there though)
- Replaced .htaccess file (nothing)
- Checking my account didn't lose admin privilege through phpmyadmin (it didn't, it's at level 10 + it has the weird administrator code
- Added a new admin account through function.php (can log in with it, still can't access dashboard)
- Increased memory limit
- Repair database tables

Kind of desperate and frustrated about it.

Thank you in advance for the help :)

Comment: Can you list the plugins you are using? Are you using any security plugins?

Comment: No security plugin in place, I mainly have Elementor, contact form 7 and WP-Rocket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok with a fresh pair of eyes, I found out what was the problem. Tables prefix! I followed what was described here : [After moving Wordpress, login works, but no admin access anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433648/after-moving-wordpress-login-works-but-no-admin-access-anymore?rq=1)

For the record, I never found it when googling or searching my answer here before posting. When posting my question I review the post stackoverflow suggested and it wasn't there either. But now it's suggested next to my post, so... great!